# Get Percentage of Gas Price Solidity, Ethereum

Tags: solidity

How can I multiply a `uint` by a decimal fraction integer? This is what I have so far - I am explicitly converting the decimal fraction integer to type `uint`. Will this have unintended consequences?

```
uint gasPriceInWei = tx.gasprice * 1000000000;
uint percentOfGasPrice = uint(transactionCostInWei) * uint(.1);
```

Comment: If it's always 0.1, just divide by 10.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this in solidity would be to divide by 10:

```
uint percentOfGasPrice = uint(transactionCostInWei)/10;
```